# Wavelets in the spaces of harmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-functions, wavelets

I plan to do something with the theory of wavelets but in harmonic function theory. My question is about this interconnection between wavelets and harmonic functions. Can you recommend me some paper or a book written to explain ideas about this theory? Thank you very much for any answer.